# How to bring canvas on top of other views

Tags: android, canvas, magnification, magnify

I am using magnifier view for my application which is a library I got from here :

https://github.com/nomanr/android-image-magnifier

I have modified this class to extend FrameLayout (It was ImageView before) to work on my FrameLayout.

It's working well except the painted canvas view stays back of all the views which are added in that custom view.

How to bring that canvas on front of those added views?

Custom view class that i am using :

```
public class ImageMagnifier extends FrameLayout {

private PointF zoomPos;
private boolean zooming = false;
private Matrix matrix;
private Paint paint;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private BitmapShader shader;
private int sizeOfMagnifier = 300;
int cheight, cwidth;

Context con;
C c = C.getInstance();
public ImageMagnifier(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
    con=context;
}

public ImageMagnifier(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
    con=context;
}

public ImageMagnifier(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
    con=context;
}

private void init() {
    zoomPos = new PointF(0, 0);
    matrix = new Matrix();
    paint = new Paint();

    cwidth = c.Width * 109 / 1280;
    cheight = cwidth * 134 / 109;
}

public void otherTouch(int x, int y) {
    if (x > c.getwidth1(28) && x < c.getwidth1(921) && y > c.getheight1(135) && y < c.getheight1(560)) {
        zoomPos.x = x - 10;
        zoomPos.y = y - 75;
        zooming = true;
        this.invalidate();

    } else {
        RemoveMagnifire();
    }
}

public void RemoveMagnifire() {
    zooming = false;
    this.invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (!zooming) {
        buildDrawingCache();
    } else {

        bitmap = getDrawingCache();
        shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP,Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);        
        paint.setShader(shader);
        matrix.reset();
        matrix.postScale(2f, 2f, zoomPos.x-10, zoomPos.y+60);

        paint.getShader().setLocalMatrix(matrix);

        int width = c.Width;
        int height = c.Height;

        float leftX = zoomPos.x - ((width * 100) / 1280);
        float topY = zoomPos.y - ((height * 250) / 720);
        float rightX = zoomPos.x +  ((width * 100) / 1280);
        float bottomY = zoomPos.y - ((height * 100) / 720);

        canvas.drawRect(leftX , topY, rightX, bottomY, paint);


    }
}

}
```

Comment: Please post your modified class, so we can be sure what you mean.

Comment: here it is :: http://pastebin.com/AzcVEWG7

Comment: OK, the fix is pretty easy, but please post the class in the question itself. Please don't link to code off-site. Future users will need to be able to view it, and won't be able to after that link dies. Thanks.

Comment: ok, thanks for suggestion. i have added code in question.

Comment: @MikeM. how to bring that view on top of other view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ViewGroup` draws its child `View`s in the `dispatchDraw()` method. We just need to move the magnifier drawing to after that happens.

The fix is simple. Move everything after the `super` call in `onDraw()` to after the `super` call in `dispatchDraw()`.

```
...

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    // Removed
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

    if (!zooming) {
        buildDrawingCache();
    }
    else {
        bitmap = getDrawingCache();
        shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        matrix.reset();
        matrix.postScale(2f, 2f, zoomPos.x - 10, zoomPos.y + 60);

        paint.getShader().setLocalMatrix(matrix);

        int width = c.Width;
        int height = c.Height;

        float leftX = zoomPos.x - ((width * 100) / 1280);
        float topY = zoomPos.y - ((height * 250) / 720);
        float rightX = zoomPos.x +  ((width * 100) / 1280);
        float bottomY = zoomPos.y - ((height * 100) / 720);

        canvas.drawRect(leftX , topY, rightX, bottomY, paint);
    }
}

...
```

You can just remove the `onDraw()` override, if you no longer need it for anything else.

Comment: ok, its working thanks for the solution. how can we remove canvas transparency ? drawRect() draws rectangle perfectly but it have some transparency.

Comment: Yeah, it'll do that if you've not set a background for your custom `View`, since it'll have a transparent background by default. You can draw another `Rect` right before the other one, with the same dimensions and location, but with a different `Paint` object, with its color set to whatever you want, with the `Paint#setColor()` method.

Comment: Well, a possible fix would be to override the `addView(View, int, ViewGroup.LayoutParams)` method, and call `destroyDrawingCache()` there. Not sure how you were getting a `StackOverflowError`, though.